# Disable Math Handwriting Icon

Tags: front-end

Does anyone know what setting in Mathematica will stop the little pop-up icon coming up for handwritten input while using the stylus on the tablet?  It's intrusive when I'm using the front end as a whiteboard for a video lesson.

[image: picture of front-end use with handwritten input option icon]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: It'd be better to find a way to turn it off entirely (maybe something in Format > Option Inspector or via editing a stylesheet?) but in the meantime, does making the specific "display" cells not editable work for you? Try selecting the cell(s) and going to Cell > Cell Properties and uncheck Editable—also try checking Deployed if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try removing the Math Recognizer from Settings app > Apps > Optional Features.

Comment: This answer works just fine for me.  I didn't know the name of the feature.